# Как парсить локальный JSON файл?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, webpack, fetch

Я использую WebPack и node.js. Моя задача - при нажатии на кнопку обновлять данные на странице, которые берутся из локального JSON файла (в последствии этот файл будет приходить из сервера, но пока упрощенный вариант). Если информация в файле обновится, то при нажатии на кнопку на странице она также должна обновиться.

Вот как я это делаю.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readFile = path => fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');

const refresh = (e) => {
  const dataFile = readFile('../data.json');
  const data = JSON.parse(dataFile);

  if (euro) {
    euro.innerHTML = data.currency.euro;
  }
  if (usd) {
    usd.innerHTML = data.currency.usd;
  }
  if (rub) {
    rub.innerHTML = data.currency.rub;
  }
}
```

И получаю ошибку: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'fs'

Перепробовал все ответы со Stackoverflow:
В webpack.config.js прописывал:

```
target: 'node'

// или

node: {
  fs: "empty"
}
```

В package.json прописывал:

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false
  }
```

Но ничего из этого не помогло.
Что мне делать?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь подключить модуль для чтения и записи файлов в операционной системе для скрипта, который будет работать в браузере? Сделайте сразу, чтобы файл приходил с сервера  и вопрос будет снят, я думаю. А так у браузера нет доступа к чтению файлов пользователя. Только один - `input type="file"`

Comment: @Leonid, есть еще вот такая возможность работы с файлами на клиенте... https://habr.com/ru/company/timeweb/blog/653703/

Answer (score 0):

Для меня самое простое это поднять Python `http.server` на локальной машине.

Требования: `python` v3

Что делать:

1. Создать папку и положить туда `json` файл.
2. Открыть CMD, сменить директорую из пункта 1 и поднять локальный сервер командой

```
py -m http.server 7999
```

3. Сделать запрос

```py
import requests
a = requests.get("http://localhost:7999/1.json")
print(a)

# out
<Response [200]>
```

Теперь мой `json` файл доступен по ссылке на локальной машине. В пункте 3, я для теста использую python. Если использовать другие способы сделать `GET` запрос, например через `curl` или `fetch` яваскрипта, все так же будет прекрасно работать.

Сразу написать функию запроса `json` от сервера, при тестировании использовать локальный адрес, на проде просто поменять `url` доступа через обычный конфиг.

Пример функции `fetch`:

```js
const url = "http://localhost:7999/1.json";
let getJsonFile = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    return json;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```